# Adding two selector inputs that include all columns of a data frame in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using a different database than mtcars, but to make this example reproducible I'll use it here.

I'm trying to create an app with a slider and two selectors.

Basically, I know how to create a selectInput if I only choose one column. In the code below, I would simply have `selectInput("cylinput", "input", choices = c(all of my choices)` and add `cyl == input$cylinput` to the filter function.

That said, if I want to create two selectInputs for all of the columns in the data frame, then I don't know how to do that. Well, I don't know how to do that once in the server side.

The code is here:

**ui:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

head(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("mpginput", "mpg", min = 10.4, max = 33.9, value = c(10.4, 33.9)),
      selectInput("xcol", "X Axis", names(mtcars)),
      selectInput("ycol", "Y Axis", names(mtcars))
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)
```

**server:**

```
server <- function(input, output){

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    Filtered <- mtcars %>%
      filter(
        mpg >= input$mpginput[1],
        mpg <= input$mpginput[2]
      )
    ggplot(Filtered, aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) +
      geom_point() 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I did come across this example when researching, and it does something similar to what I'm looking to do. But, I'm not that familiar with base graphics or the code used to create the plot:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify how do you want input$xcol and input$ycol be used in the server code.

Comment: @XiongbingJin So, I would like to have the graph start with `mpg == input$xcol`, and `qsec == input$ycol`. But, then whenever the user wants to pick a different column, they can pick, let's say cyl, then the app would react and display the column of data on whichever axis they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Sorry about the poorly worded question. Honestly, I'm very new to Shiny, and didn't quite understand the code very well.

Basically, all I did was used `choices = c()` instead of the `names(mtcars)`, which didn't work for me.

Then called the input$xcol and input$ycol in ggplot2 graph.

**ui:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

head(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("mpginput", "mpg", min = 10.4, max = 33.9, value = c(10.4, 33.9)),
      selectInput("xcol", "X Axis", choices = c("mpg","cyl","hp","drat","disp","wt","gear","carb","am","vs")),
      selectInput("ycol", "Y Axis", choices = c("mpg","cyl","hp","drat","disp","wt","gear","carb","am","vs"))
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)
```

**server:**

```
server <- function(input, output){

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    Filtered <- mtcars %>% 
      filter(
        mpg >= input$mpginput[1],
        mpg <= input$mpginput[2]
      )
    ggplot(Filtered) +
      geom_point(aes_string(x = input$xcol, y = input$ycol))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```